# How can I solve an error while using "justMyCode" as false in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am using the VS Code for a python file debugging.
However, I could not step into functions, and non of soluions online worked for my case.

My launch.json file looks like this.
[image]

I have changed "request" to "test", or set "debugOptions": ["DebugStdLib"]. But it was not successful. The error message always pops up as:
[image]

Comment: Please provide more details on how to debug and also on [how to configure launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options) should help you.            Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

[`request`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_request) has two settings

> - launch: start the debugger on the file specified in `program`
> - attach: attach the debugger to an already running process. See [Remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-script-debugging-with-ssh) for an example.

It may help to configure *launch.json* according to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) or use the default *launch.json*.